# How to link sqlite3 library with makefile

Tags: c, sqlite, makefile

I'm trying to link `sqlite3` to my project linked with a makefile.
I read instructions to include `slite3.c/.h` files in my project but include an external library seems preferable to me.

The aim is to `#include <sqlite3.h>` instead of `#include "sqlite3.h"`.
Is there a way to do this?

Here is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -MMD -coverage
LDFLAGS= -lcmocka -coverage


all: main

main: connect_struct_UI.o UTest.o UTest_UI.o patient.o
     $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $^

run_test: main
     ./main ; \
     lcov --capture --directory . --output-file coverage.info ; \
     genhtml coverage.info --output-directory ../tests/coverage ; \
     valgrind ./$<
```

Thanks!

Comment: With C and C++ programs, I find it better to include sqlite directly in the program instead of linking an external library. That way you know exactly what version you're using, and can configure it with any options you might need. Sucks to find out after the fact that such-and-such OS's version of sqlite doesn't include a feature your program uses.

Comment: I understand your point of view but it's actually not the way I want to organize my project in this case @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add

```
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs sqlite3`
```

at the top of the Makefile